# Add Authorization JSONP Request Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I use JSONP on a request with a basic auth so I want to add the header **Authorization** in my request to retrieve the token.

I test that:

```
$scope.doRequest = function() {
    $http({method: 'JSONP', url: 'http://apilder-apiscory.fr/token?callback=JSON_CALLBACK',headers: {'Authorization': 'Basic basic'}})
        .success(function(data){
            console.log(data.token);
    });
```

But always code http status 401.

How can resolve my problem?

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

JSONP requests work by generating a `<script>` element in the page.

There is no way to specify arbitrary HTTP request headers when you are using JSONP.

The solution, which requires the cooperation of the API provider, is to use CORS and XMLHttpRequest instead of JSONP.

Comment: So how can I access it (I have two different domains)?

Comment: @Bourg — I refer you back to the third and final paragraph of the answer.

Comment: Sorry I publish the comment after read the second paragraph... Thank you so much. So it's the provider who must implement CORS indeed.